# Newbie's question on Rspec test in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am newbie in rspec test. I have two questions on rspec test in Rails.

If I have a '**Car**' model which is an **ActiveRecord**,

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def get_color
    ..
  end
end
```

**Question 1.** In rspec test (I have all the gems and configurations ready), what's the difference between

```
before(:each) do
    @my_car=Factory.create(:car, params)
end
```

and

```
before(:each) do
    @my_car=Car.new(params)
    @my_car.save
end
```

(I mean what's the difference **inside** rspec test scope, dont they have the same effect inside rspec test? not only inside **before(:each) do** statement, but also **describe...do** statement)

**Question 2.** As you see in my **car** model, there is a instance function `get_color`, can I invoke this instance function in my rspec test in the following way?

```
@my_car=Factory.create(:car, params)
@my_car.get_color #Can I call instance method in rspec test?
```

I have tried this, but it seems the instance method does not return the result as expected in rspec test. But works outside rspec test code, but I am not sure.

Anyone can makes me clear about the two questions?

Comment: It's better to do 2 questions instead of only one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1 :

There are no difference between the 2 statement instead the using of Factory girl. With Factory girl you can have some default behavior during the creation of your Object. In the second case you need do it yourself.

Question 2 :

You need test your method. If by example return 0 you can add :

```
it 'should return 0' do
  @my_car.get_color.should == 0
end
```

We can't be more specific with more code

Answer (score 0):

Q1 : It's practically the same, though factories are more flexible and i prefer them.

Q2 : You can execute @my_car.get_color, but just executing it does not mean anything. You either need to check whether it fulfills a condition(using should probably) or stub it to return a value that you want, without actually executing(a common rspec practice).